# Trying to replace Ubuntu with Kubuntu but "Replace" option does not show up?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, kubuntu

I have Ubuntu dual booting with Windows. I would like to replace it with Kubuntu but when going to install from USB that option is not there (if I do this with a Ubuntu USB disk it does give the option to replace just Ubuntu or wipe the whole disk.

Might there be an option I am missing? Does Ubuntu "see itself" but Kubuntu does not?

Thanks all :)

Comment: And you are using the same boot method as you installed Ubuntu? Either Legacy or UEFI?

Comment: Yes, I used Universal USB Installer both times with the same disk (formatted of course), same settings.  -Thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu and Kubuntu are incompatible, seeing as they are different operating systems with different installers, slightly different core files, extremely different default software, etc.

I would recommend doing either:

1. backing up all your important files in a separate partition, then installing Kubuntu over the Ubuntu partition.
2. Just install Plasma and the KDE software that you want. You can change the desktop environment you want to login to from the login screen.

Comment: Thank you! I see, I had just previously done the opposite though, replaced Kunbuntu with Unbuntu.

Comment: It must be the installer. Kubuntu installer probably doesn't have a replace option then.